# Call object from another View

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm developping an app, which make an request to a webservice, once the webservice answer (in JSON) I decode the result in an other view (repository.swift)

I just need to use the value which are stored in repository, in one of my other view (Swype.swift)

This is my code to decode JSON :

```
if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: nil, error: nil) as? [String:AnyObject] {
                    for (_, value) in json {
                        if let dict = value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                            let repo = Repository(jsonData: dict)
                            repos.append(repo)
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And my "repository" class :

```
class Repository {

var idobjet: String?
var title: String?
var price: String?
var description: String?
var added: String?
var userid: String?
var user_name: String?
var user_zipCode: String?
var category_id: String?
var category_label: String?
var subcategory_id: String?
var subcategory_label: String?
var picture_url: String?

init(jsonData: [String:AnyObject]) {
    self.idobjet = jsonData["id"] as? String
    self.title = jsonData["title"] as? String
    self.price = jsonData["price"] as? String
    self.description = jsonData["description"] as? String
    self.added = jsonData["addedDate"] as? String
    self.userid = jsonData["userid"] as? String
    self.user_name = jsonData["user_name"] as? String
    self.user_zipCode = jsonData["user_zipCode"] as? String
    self.category_id = jsonData["category_id"] as? String
    self.category_label = jsonData["category_label"] as? String
    self.subcategory_id = jsonData["subcategory_id"] as? String
    self.subcategory_label = jsonData["subcategory_label"] as? String
    self.picture_url = jsonData["picture_url"] as? String

   }
}

var repos = [Repository]()
```

I need to get "picture_url", "title" and "Description" value in my other view, to create an Imageview and some other fields :

```
//Construct the imgUrl to get an image URL for the pages
                let urlString: NSString =  "picture_url" Values
                if let url = NSURL(string: urlString as String) {
                    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                        newCard.image = UIImage(data: data)!

                        newCard.content = "title" value
                        newCard.desc = "price" value
                        self.data.append(newCard)
                        NSLog("fetch new data")

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You need to declare the properties you want to access as public first. Second, it's not clear from your question how your classes are setup. Either instantiate your repository class in your desired class and then do the parsing, or look at creating it as a singleton perhaps.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: The question is, how to use the value of the "picture_url" var which is declared in "repository.swift"? In my second controller.

Comment: You can have a property in your `SecondViewController` and while moving from 'repository.swift' to  `SecondViewController` in segue method you can set that property.

Comment: no, repository is just a view to store some value, it's not like if i had some push segue. I already used theses values for a table view with "repos[indexPath.row].picture_url!" but for a ViewController it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many view controllers make use of this fields, probably the simplest solution is to define a property that holds your `Repository` object in your destination view controller and then set it in the parent view controller before the segue (using the `(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` method).

On the other hand, if these fields have to be accessed frequently, it's probably more convenient to set a data model class which view controllers can rely on.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so there are multiple ways to handle this.

**Here is what I suggest:**

initialize a Repository object as a global variable.

```
var repo:Repository?

class SomeViewControllerOne: UIViewController { 
    func initializeRepository() {
        repo = Repository(....)
        // continue with initialization
    }
}

class AnotherViewControllerTwo: UIViewController {
    func useRepository() {
        if let repository = repo {
            print(repository.title)
        }
    }
}
```

the object "repo" is global, and can be used application wide. just be carful, because the object is an optional.